# Dates from 1900-01-01 are added to my 'Time' after using df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(phData['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am a self taught coder (for around a year, so new). Here is my data

```
phData = pd.read_excel('phone call log & duration.xlsx')
called from called to   Date    Time    Duration in (sec)
0   7722078014  7722012013  2017-07-01  10:00:00    303
1   7722078014  7722052018  2017-07-01  10:21:00    502
2   7722078014  7450120521  2017-07-01  10:23:00    56

The dtypes are:
called from                   int64
called to                     int64
Date                 datetime64[ns]
Time                         object
Duration in (sec)             int64
dtype: object

phData['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(phData['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')


phData.head(2)

called from called to   Date    Time    Duration in (sec)
0   7722078014  7722012013  2017-07-01  1900-01-01 10:00:00 303
1   7722078014  7722052018  2017-07-01  1900-01-01 10:21:00 502
```

I've managed to change the 'Time' to  datetime64[ns] but somehow dates have been added?? From where I have no idea? I want to be able to analyse the `Date` and `Time` using Pandas which I'm happy to do. To explore calls made between dates and time, frequency etc. I think also I will be able to save it so it will work in Orange3. But Orange3 won't recognise the Time as a time format. I've tried stripping out the `1900-01-01` but get an error saying it can only be done if an object. I think the Time isn't a `datetime` but a `datetime.time` ??? and I'm not sure why this matters and how to simply have 2 `columns` one `Date` and another `Time`, that Pandas will recognise for me to mine. I have looked at countless posts and that's where I found how to use `pd.to_datetime` and that my issue might be `datetime.time` but I'm stuck after this.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas doesn't have such dtype as Time. You can have either `datetime` or `timedelta` dtype.

**Option 1**: combine Date and Time into single column:

```
In [23]: df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date') + ' ' + df.pop('Time'))

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   called from   called to  Duration in (sec)           TimeStamp
0   7722078014  7722012013                303 2017-07-01 10:00:00
1   7722078014  7722052018                502 2017-07-01 10:21:00
2   7722078014  7450120521                 56 2017-07-01 10:23:00
```

**Option 2**: convert `Date` to `datetime` and `Time` to `timedelta` dtype:

```
In [27]: df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

In [28]: df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   called from   called to       Date     Time  Duration in (sec)
0   7722078014  7722012013 2017-07-01 10:00:00                303
1   7722078014  7722052018 2017-07-01 10:21:00                502
2   7722078014  7450120521 2017-07-01 10:23:00                 56

In [30]: df.dtypes
Out[30]:
called from                    int64
called to                      int64
Date                  datetime64[ns]
Time                 timedelta64[ns]
Duration in (sec)              int64
dtype: object
```