# Converting pandas object to timedelta results in NaT

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a DataFrame with three columns, one date and two times. It's like this:

```
         date hour_in hour_out
0  01/06/2016        08:15      19:37   
1  02/06/2016        08:26      17:31   
2  03/06/2016        08:08      21:31
```

I'm trying to convert `hour_in`and `hour_out` to timedelta using this code (which is based on an answer on this question [Dates from 1900-01-01 are added to my 'Time' after using df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(phData['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199910/dates-from-1900-01-01-are-added-to-my-time-after-using-dftime-pd-to-date)):

```
df['hora_entrada'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['hora_entrada'], errors='coerce')
df['hora_saida']  = pd.to_timedelta(df['hora_saida'] , errors='coerce')
```

After the cast, my column is converted to the correct dtype `timedelta64[ns]`, but all the values are set to `NaT`. My `df.info()` returns this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 439 entries, 0 to 438
Data columns (total 4 columns):
data            439 non-null datetime64[ns]
hour_in         0 non-null timedelta64[ns]
hour_out        0 non-null timedelta64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), timedelta64[ns](2)
```

And the data output is like this:

```
          data hora_entrada hora_saida
0   2016-06-01          NaT        NaT
1   2016-06-02          NaT        NaT
2   2016-06-03          NaT        NaT
```

I've tried to convert the time columns to `datetime` and then to `timedelta` but I got strange results. Here's an example:

```
          data          hora_entrada            hora_saida
0   2016-06-01 -25567 days +08:15:00 -25567 days +19:37:00
1   2016-06-02 -25567 days +08:26:00 -25567 days +17:31:00
2   2016-06-03 -25567 days +08:08:00 -25567 days +21:31:00
```

I think it's because when I convert it to `datetime` it's appended to the hour a date `1900-01-01`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
In [24]: pd.to_timedelta(df.hour_in + ':00', errors='coerce')
Out[24]:
0   08:15:00
1   08:26:00
2   08:08:00
Name: hour_in, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked with your solution. Can you just explain why this approuch works and the one that I was trying don't?

Comment: @aiquis, `pd.to_timedelta` expects either a full time string (format:  `%H:%M:%S`) or a numerical # of units (seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds) from `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`...